# How to change a directed graph into a complete graph by deleting nodes, and keep as many nodes as possible？

Tags: graph-theory

Here, a complete directed graph is defined as a graph in which every edge has a direction, and every two vertices are connected by two edges with opposite directions, and the vertex has one edge to itself.

In other words, the adjacency matrix of the final completely directed graph does not contain 0

So now, let's randomly give a directed graph, The nodes in the graph are numbered from 0 to n, and the edges of the graph are given by the adjacency matrix of n * n, how to change this directed graph into a complete graph by deleting nodes, and keep as many nodes as possible?

Your algorithm should be able to provide the final set of reserved nodes. If there are multiple final results, you can choose to only provide one, but of course, it is better to provide all the results.

Comment: " the vertex has one edge to itself."  What does this mean?

Comment: This sounds like the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Answer (score 0):

```
Loop V1 over vertices
  IF V1 does not have a self loop
       Delete V1
Loop V1 over remaining vertices
  Loop V2 over vertices that have an edge V1 -> V2
      IF edge V2 -> V1 does not exist
           Delete whichever of V1,V2 has the fewer outgoing edges
```

Comment: Take a complete graph, say K5 with vertices 1 to 5, including a [self loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(graph_theory)) on each vertex. Add vertex 6 such that vertices 1 to 5 each have an outgoing edge to the new vertex, but there are no outgoing edges from vertex 6. The desired answer would be vertices 1-5 (the original complete graph), but your algorithm would delete each of these vertices and leave only vertex 6.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either, nor are you likely to find a greedy algorithm to solve this problem. As I alluded to in the comments, this is the problem of finding a [maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs). The decision problem of determining whether there is a clique of size k in a graph is one of Karp's original NP-complete problems with a time complexity for the naive approach of O(nCk).

Comment: In this case, let G1=K4 and G2=K5. All vertices of G1,G2 have self loops. Add edges from each vertex in G1 to every vertex in G2. The vertices from G1 now have an out-degree of 9, while the vertices of G2 have an out-degree of 5 (including self loops). On the resulting graph, your algorithm will return G1.

Comment: G1 is a correct answer.

Comment: From "keep as many nodes as possible" I understood that the OP was looking for a maximum clique rather than a [maximal clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_a_single_maximal_clique) with possibly fewer vertices.